# record an async function execution time in python

Tags: python, async-await

I have an async function e.g. `a`. It is used as `b = await a()`

How can I record the time it takes for this `a()` to finish its execution?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `time.monotonic()`.

For example:

```
import asyncio
import time


async def a():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    return 1

async def main():
    start_time = time.monotonic()

    b = await a()

    print('time: ', time.monotonic() - start_time)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Prints:

```
time:  3.002365263993852
```